# Vuelidate check 1 rule only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuejs2, vuelidate

I have a huge input form which is needed to be populated with data and be able to save progress, to finish the form later, BUT only when the form fits 1 custom rule only:

- **form is able to be saved when it not containing any forbidden words(let's say that forbidden words are [TEST1, TEST2])**

That means that is for example I have validations rules like this:

```js
validations: {
  A: {
    required,
    $each: {
      Aa: { required },
      Ab: { required, dontHaveForbiddenWords },
      Ac: { required, dontHaveForbiddenWords }
    },
  },
  B: {
    required,
    Ba: { required, dontHaveForbiddenWords },
    Bb: { required },
  }
  // ... a lot of additional fields
}
```

**In this case, I want the form to be able to be saved when all fields are empty(cos it DO NOT CONTAIN forbidden words)** even if it has unfilled required fields.

The problem is that the form has an `$invalid` state due to `required` rule, and I have no idea how to bypass it.

Comment: Add `required` field validation dynamically. i.e. While saving don't add required field validation. Only `onSave` add this required field validation.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I have no idea is it even implementable, the form has validators all of them are preseted, may you have an idea or a resource where I can read about it?

Comment: In case it's possible for empty fields to be valid, they are not *required*, and it's incorrect to use `required`. From the description, I don't see why it's even needed. You could omit it, or add custom validator that conditionally checks value, depending on what you want

Comment: @EstusFlask I didn't understand what you mean by "they are not required", they are using this rule, not all in my project but all here in the example. Why is it **incorrect** to use required?

Comment: "In this case, I want the form to be able to be saved when all fields are empty" - they are not required here

Comment: @EstusFlask they are required all the time, that's was my problem

I wanted to implement some kind of a switch, as you said to turn this required rule on and off, I will post my solution rn, it's kinda bad but it does its job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The working solution was to use *JSON.stringify()*

My team mate it to stringify `validationState`, and test it on a regex string that contains name of our validationRule, which in my case is `dontHaveForbiddenWords`, and check for a `false` value, that means that at least 1 rule is failed on entire form:

```js
hasForbiddenCharacters() {
  const validationStateString = JSON.stringify(this.$v.currentOffer, null, 0)
  const hasForbiddenCharacters = /\"dontHaveForbiddenWords\":false/.test(validationStateString)

  return hasForbiddenCharacters;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### **UPDATE: This answer is not working, it was a fluke and bad testing from my side, the flag that I set up as the conditional check is NOT reapplied on `this.$v.$touch()` and stays with a default value all the time**

As @EstusFlask suggest I've created a custom validator so I could turn it off in some cases, it uses a top-level variable instead of a parameter because I want to overrule this validator for all fields at once, also in my project I have conditional `required validators`, and I found not create a better solution, would be glad if you will edit my solution:

```js
import { helpers } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';

let isRequired = true;
const customRequiredValidator = (value) => {
 return isRequired ? helpers.req(value) : true;
}
```

later in code, I have 2 handlers:

- onSave() where I am turning the `required` rule OFF
- onSumbit() where I am setting the `required` rule back ON

smth like this

```js
onSave() {
 isRequired = false;
 if (this.$v.$invalid) {
   isRequired = true;
   // show alert
   return;
 }
 isRequired = true;
 // save form progress
}

// isRequired is always true after onSave
onSubmit() {
 this.$v.$touch(); // to trigger the validation
 if (this.$v.$invalid) return; // show alert

 // sumbit the form
}
```

Comment: In Vuelidate 2, I'd just go with two different validations, for save and submit, based on the same validator set. It could be conditionally added `required`, or custom validator that behaves differently on some model property